# JavaScript: Submit Form on Enter

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, but I'm working on a bit of a math quiz. The idea is that the user (a first grade student) will answer one question at a time and then all of the user's answers will be displayed on a popup, which will also display feedback about whether or not the user's answer is correct. I have it pretty much good to go, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the form submit when the user presses "Enter."

Any help would be much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Math Worksheet</title>
    <script src="addition.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Englebert' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="formSec">
        <table id="addProblem" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><h2>Problem <span id="outOf">1</span> of 12</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="1" align="right"><input id="carryOver"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" id="firstNum">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>+</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" id="secondNum">16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><hr id="sepLine"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input onKeyPress="return checkSubmit(event)" id="userAnswer" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input id="submit" type="button" onClick="submitAnswer()" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// first number in addition problem
var numOne = [48,39,16,43,37,23,44,13,37,28,48,16];   

// second number in addition problem
var numTwo = [16,22,25,18,46,49,18,39,25,17,9,28];

// counter variable
var i = 0;

// array for user answers
var answers = [];

// arrays to display validity
var valid = [];
var equality = [];

// submit when "enter" is pressed
function checkSubmit(e) {
   if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      document.forms[0].submit();
   }
}

// check and store answer's validity
function submitAnswer() {
    var guessed = Number(document.getElementById('userAnswer').value);
    var checkAnswer = 'Correct!';

    if (guessed != numOne[i]+numTwo[i]) {
        checkAnswer = 'Incorrect!\nThe answer is'+' '+Number(numOne[i]+numTwo[i])+'.';
        valid[i] = 'Incorrect';
        equality[i] = ' &NotEqual; ';
    } else if (guessed == numOne[i]+numTwo[i]) {
        valid[i] = 'Correct';
        equality[i] = ' = ';
    }

    if(confirm(checkAnswer) && i<11) {
        // next problem
        i++;
        document.getElementById('outOf').innerHTML=i+1;
        document.getElementById('firstNum').innerHTML=numOne[i];
        document.getElementById('secondNum').innerHTML=numTwo[i];

        // saves user's answer
        answers.push(document.getElementById('userAnswer').value);

        // reset the answer and carry over to blank
        document.getElementById('userAnswer').value = '';
        document.getElementById('carryOver').value = '';

        // return focus to answer box
        document.getElementById('userAnswer').focus();
    } else if(i==11) { // create popup window with user's answers
        var results=window.open('','name','height=650,width=1000');

        answers.push(document.getElementById('userAnswer').value);

        results.document.write('<html><head><title>Math Worksheet Results</title>');
        results.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">');
        results.document.write('<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Englebert" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
        results.document.write('</head><body><div id="resultsMain">');
        results.document.write('<header><h1>Student Results</h1></header><div id="results">');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">1. ' + valid[0] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[0] + ' + ' + numTwo[0] + equality[0] + answers[0] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">2. ' + valid[1] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[1] + ' + ' + numTwo[1] + equality[1] + answers[1] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">3. ' + valid[2] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[2] + ' + ' + numTwo[2] + equality[2] + answers[2] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">4. ' + valid[3] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[3] + ' + ' + numTwo[3] + equality[3] + answers[3] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">5. ' + valid[4] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[4] + ' + ' + numTwo[4] + equality[4] + answers[4] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">6. ' + valid[5] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[5] + ' + ' + numTwo[5] + equality[5] + answers[5] + '</p></div>');        

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">7. ' + valid[6] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[6] + ' + ' + numTwo[6] + equality[6] + answers[6] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">8. ' + valid[7] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[7] + ' + ' + numTwo[7] + equality[7] + answers[7] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">9. ' + valid[8] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[8] + ' + ' + numTwo[8] + equality[8] + answers[8] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">10. ' + valid[9] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[9] + ' + ' + numTwo[9] + equality[9] + answers[9] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">11. ' + valid[10] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[10] + ' + ' + numTwo[10] + equality[10] + answers[10] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<div class="prob"><p class="probNum">12. ' + valid[11] + '</p><p class="userProb">');
        results.document.write(numOne[11] + ' + ' + numTwo[11] + equality[11] + answers[11] + '</p></div>');

        results.document.write('<br class="clear"></div></div></body></html>');
        results.document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to submit the `value` and get the value to be displayed at another page?

Comment: Yes. Right now you have to click "Submit" to move onto the next question. I'd like to be able to just hit "Enter" from the input field in order to move on.

Comment: Do you need to `redirect` to another page?

Comment: Submitting on enter is the default behaviour, no script required. Change the submit button to type submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you couldn't replace `document.forms[0].submit();` with `submitAnswer();`?

If you want the form to actually submit (i.e. POST, which is not what I think your intention is), but for the sake of completeness, the reason why you are running into issues with your submit syntax is that you have an element with the name `submit`, which has effectively overridden the form's submit function. You can instead use this alternative to submit the form (if you don't want to rename the element):

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.forms[0]);
```

Comment: And in browsers that don't implement *HTMLFormElement* or prototype inheritance?

Comment: I believe object prototypes have existed as part of all ECMAScript implementations, and HTMLFormElement is supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Until HTML5, DOM interfaces were independant of the scripting language and while some browsers implemented ECMAScript–like inheritance, some didn't. With HTML5 that changed, however not all browsers fully implement prototype inheritance or modification of host objects. IE 7 didn't IE 8 only partially. Is that a "major browser"? [Extending host objects](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) has similar pitfalls to [extending built–in ECMAScript objects](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/), so should only be done after careful consideration.

Comment: The simple answer is as proposed by Toto: use a real submit button, remove the name "submit" and put the submit listener on the form. That way no additional scripting is required.

Answer (score 1):

The one you are looking for is the default behavior of an input element in a form when you press enter

http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/pEJxd/

if you want `submitAnswer()` to be execuded when you press enter you need to add the onsubmit event to the form: `onSubmit=submitAnswer();` like here http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/H9vL4/